# Import <scope>provided</scope> dependencies from maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have created a maven package of type `<packaging>pom</packaging>` which I would include in other maven projects as 'base' package providing some dependencies which I need always.

```xml
    <project>
        <groupId>com.projectbase.pom</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectbase-pom</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.18</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

There are also dependencies of scope `<scope>provided</scope>` where I declare some exclusions etc. In my child project I'm adding this maven package to get all the dependencies I declared in the base package like this:

```xml
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.projectbase.pom</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectbase-pom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

This works fine for all non `<scope>provided</scope>` depdencies but the `provided` dependencies are not included. When I use my base `pom.xml` as parent in my child project, it works as expected:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.projectbase.pom</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectbase-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
```

The problem is, that the child pom already has a parent so this is no opportunity. Is there any other way to import the `provided` dependencies in my child pom, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the dependencies you add via the pom dependency are transitive dependencies. The scope `provided` is not transitive.

You remove the scope from all the dependencies in the pom dependency. Then you write a BOM (a pom with only dependencyManagement) and import it in your dependencyManagement with scope `import`. This BOM then sets the correct scopes.

Comment: The dependencyManagement section in the BOM should contain the provided dependency without scope, is this correct?

Comment: The BOM should contain the scopes.